# Deleting an entry from a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**How can I delete a specific element (eg: using its id) from a JSON array?**

A delete button will perform this task, passing its id.

For example, how to delete item with id = 2 :

Note: id number 2 can be in an array index of 10 or 20.

> "id": 2, "date": "27 Mar 2018", "name": "name 2", "type":
>   "meeting"

```
        var id = 1;
        var events = [{
                "id": id++,
                "date": "26 Mar 2018",
                "name": "name 1",
                "type": "task"
            },
            {
                "id": id++,
                "date": "27 Mar 2018",
                "name": "name 2",
                "type": "meeting"
            },
            {
                "id": id++,
                "date": "27 Mar 2018",
                "name": "name 3",
                "type": "meeting"
            }

        ];

        events.push({
            "id": id++,
            "date": "25 Mar 2018",
            "name": "name 4",
            "type": "meeting"
        });
```

Comment: Use `findIndex` and `splice` ? Considering your JSON was parsed to the object literal.

Comment: That is a JavaScript object literal.  JSON is a *string*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below

```js
var events = [{
                "id": 1,
                "date": "26 Mar 2018",
                "name": "name 1",
                "type": "task"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "date": "27 Mar 2018",
                "name": "name 2",
                "type": "meeting"
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "date": "27 Mar 2018",
                "name": "name 3",
                "type": "meeting"
            }

        ];
        let entry_to_delete=events.find(e => e.id === 10);
        events.splice(events.indexOf(entry_to_delete),1);
        console.log(events);
```